# Bundle getArguments returns null

Tags: java, android, fragment, bundle

First of all other questions not helped me and i can't to solve my problem.
Ok now i have 2 fragments, i have to get from one fragment the checked elements, add them to bundle and get in other fragment. I'm doing debug and i see that in `setArguments()` he saves the checked elements, but when i want to get the arguments in other fragment, it returns null. What's wrong?

```
public class FragmentLanguage extends Fragment {

public static final String TEXT = "language";
PersonalInfoFragment info = new PersonalInfoFragment();

View mainView;
ListView listView;

Button clear, next;
MyAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    listView = mainView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    select_Lang();

    checkButtonClick();

    return mainView;
}

private void select_Lang() {

    ArrayList<Item_obj> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    Item_obj item_obj = new Item_obj("Armenian", R.drawable.download, false);
    itemList.add(item_obj);
    item_obj = new Item_obj("Russian", R.drawable.download, false);
    itemList.add(item_obj);

    //create an ArrayAdapter from the String Array
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_items, itemList);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void checkButtonClick() {
    next = mainView.findViewById(R.id.next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList<Item_obj> arrayList = adapter.items_list;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                Item_obj item = arrayList.get(i);
                if (item.isSelected()) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(TEXT, item.getLanguage());
                    info.setArguments(bundle);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                            new PersonalInfoFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Ok and here's the fragment where i want to get the saved arguments.

```
public class PersonalInfoFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TEXT = "language";

View mainView;

EditText skills_description;
Button  save, languages;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_info, container, false);
    init(mainView);

    return mainView;
}

private void init(View v) {
    skills_description = v.findViewById(R.id.skills);
    languages = v.findViewById(R.id.select_language);
    save = v.findViewById(R.id.save);

    languages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    new FragmentLanguage()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), bundle.getString(TEXT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

But he returns null. How to fix it? Thanks.

Here's myAdapter class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ct;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Item_obj> objects;
PersonalInfoFragment info = new PersonalInfoFragment();

MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item_obj> itemObj) {
    ct = context;
    objects = itemObj;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ct
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_items, parent, false);
    }

    Item_obj io = getItem_obj(position);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.select_lang)).setText(io.language);
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(io.image);

    CheckBox cb = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangeList);
    cb.setTag(position);
    cb.setChecked(io.isSelected);

    return view;
}

Item_obj getItem_obj(int position) {
    return (Item_obj) getItem(position);
}

ArrayList<Item_obj> getCheck() {
    ArrayList<Item_obj> item = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Item_obj i : objects) {
        if (i.isSelected)
            item.add(i);
    }
    return item;
}


OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangeList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        getItem_obj((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).isSelected = isChecked;
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass info in replace() method your problem will solved-
but You should commit your fragment outside the for loop

```
   int itemCount = 0;
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
         Item_obj item = arrayList.get(i);
        if (item.isSelected()) {
                itemCount++;
              bundle.putString(TEXT+"i"+, item.getLanguage());
         }
        }
       bundle.putInt("itemCount",itemCount);
        info.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
       info).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Now you can get all values on other fragment as -

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int itemCount = bundle.getInt("itemCount",0);
        if(itemCount > 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount ; i++) {
              String language =  bundle.getString(TEXT+"i");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok but now he gets only the last checked element

Comment: In my code, In for loop if items are checked than code is adding each checked  item with keys language0, language1, language2 .....  in bundle and it is also saving count of item with key "itemCount" in bundle. On Other frangment on the bases of "itemCount" you can get how many languages were added. Using for loop you can get all language using keys by adding 0,1,2 in "language"

Comment: Ok man thanks, but i have question. How can i do this bundle part in adapter class. In adapter i'm using ArrayAdapter

Comment: Ok i'll try to do myself, if something will not work i'll say you okay? Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi, i added my Adapter code in my question. Please can you tell me how to do this bundle part not in Main class, but in adapter class? Thank you.

Comment: your next button and next.setOnClickListener() is outside the adapter. You want to sent bundle on next button click event. So it is not possible you call bundle passing event in  adapter.

Answer (score 0):

your `info` member is not the same as `new PersonalInfoFragment()`. On the former you are setting the `Bundle` on the latter you don't. Unfortunately you are using the latter to commit the transaction

Answer (score 0):

You are globalizing PersonalInfoFragment and setting bundle to its reference and you are sending a new object which doesn't have any bundle

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                        new PersonalInfoFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Replace `new PersonalInfoFragment() with info`